# How to run Async Tasks of running a Script and closing the App together

Tags: java

I have a Java Swings app in which when a user clicks on 'Check Updates' Button, the code runs an external Powershell Script to download the update file, then overwrite the existing JAR file.

But I want to close the JAR as well from the code so that it doesn't have 'open file' issue while overwriting it.

This is the code I am have written:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
  SharedLibrary.RunDownloadUpdateFileScript(NewVersion);
});                 
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        System.exit(0);
});
```

The System.exit command must run as soon as the method above it is executed. It shouldn't wait for the above method to complete.

So how can I achieve this?

Comment: It already doesn't wait for anything. `System.exit` terminates the JVM. Though I'd argue you shouldn't just close the app on user. Let him decide whether he's ready or not.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Thanks for the reply. User already agrees prior to running this code by clicking Yes. The problem in this code is, the execution doesnt go in SharedLibrary.RunDownloadUpdateFileScript at all.  I tested this by putting a messagebox inside it.

Comment: "the execution doesnt go in RunDownloadUpdateFileScript" <- because it doesn't wait for anything to finish, exactly like you told it to.

Comment: Thats what my question is, how can I run that function and Exit independently of each other?

Comment: You can't. If they run truly independently, you aren't guaranteed that download is entered into. `System.exit` is a meanie like that.

Comment: Are you, by chance, interested in terminating VM *after* the download request is sent?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Yes I am interested only in terminating JAR after the download request it sent. But the problem is just at the end of that external script, the running jar needs to be replaced.

Comment: Ok. Is `RunDownload...` synchronous? Will it not return until the download finished?

Comment: Yes it is synchronous, it waits for completion of the script then returns the result.

Comment: Then I'm afraid it's not possible to do what you want. If it's synchonous and waits for whole process to complete, both it and snippet code are non-functional, as there is an effective race condition over the downloaded file: it could work if you delay `System.exit` call enough so that download request is sent but results haven't arrived yet, but it still might break randomly. Split your app into separate jars, one for main app and the other for updating. Or, what I'd prefer, is you don't wait for download to finish, then it's an easy solution I can post right now.

Comment: "don't wait for download to finish" Can you explain this please?

Comment: In terms of `java.lang.Process`, you use `waitFor()` to wait for script to finish. If you don't call that method, then processing is async, and you can safely terminate.